# stl export failing, error text below

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, export, 3d-printing

trying to make a 3d print for a wolf, and blender is failing to export it
what is this error?[image: error message screenshot]

EDIT: .blend file at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DMchGNMUrspz8p1WPO67qRL-n38wzoLw

Comment: Can you upload the blend file?

Comment: yes, ill put a google drive link down EDIT:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DMchGNMUrspz8p1WPO67qRL-n38wzoLw

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: im using blender from PortableApps.com on my flash drive, could it be that the library is simply missing from my USB?